# How to prevent AWS Lambda from deleting message from SQS queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a Lambda function, which will be sending SNS notification when a message is sent to SQS Queue.
But i observe that Lambda will delete the message from queue once it has processed it and its been mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_gb/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

Is there a way i can make the lambda fail, without actually throwing a new Exception in java.

Comment: What's wrong with deleting the processed massage? That's the entire point of using SQS-Lambda architecture.

Comment: there is another team which needs those messages and they process the data sent in message, when my application is deleting those messages they are unable to find them, so we need the messages be present in queue.

Comment: In this case there should be a second SQS queue, one per team. Thus, your SNS would publish a message to two queues. This is called [fan-out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html) architecture.

Comment: There are situations where I would like Lambda to be triggered by SQS, but to let a downstream service handle deleting the message. E.g., sqs->lambda->stepfn. It's a shame that AWS doesn't have this option

Answer (score 4):

From you description, it seems that you should consider using [fan-out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html) scenario for your use-case:

> The "fanout" scenario is when an Amazon SNS message is sent to a topic and then **replicated and pushed to multiple Amazon SQS queues**, HTTP endpoints, or email addresses.

[image]

In this scenario, your SNS would publish a message to **two SQS queues**. Subsequently, each team would have its own messages to work, and you wouldn't need to forcefully terminate your lambda to keep a processed message in a single queue.

Comment: Yeah i understand this architecture, but we have SNS here sending emails to groups.

Comment: @SrikanthJosyula Could you clarify which email? In your question there is no mention of an email. Who's sending email? The original SNS topic, a lambda?

Comment: My Lambda function reads the message when sent to SQS queue and there is key inside the message if its false, my Lambda code which has SNS inside it sends the emails to group. so here when my lambda is reading the SQS message even in the case where key is true, where i dont need to send mail, those messages are also being deleted.. ideally those messages need to be present inside queue for other teams to process it

Comment: @SrikanthJosyula I see. So instead of fan-out, I think "chaining" would be better: SNS -> lambda1. the lambda1 would send email, and forward the message to SQS queue to be read by second team (lambda2). For example: `SNS->lambda1 (send email, forwards msg)->SQS->lambda2 of the second team`

Answer (score 4):

By default, SQS to Lambda integration means that messages in que will become invisible once the function begins processing it, and will be deleted from the que once the function has completed.

If the function fails (bad exit), then the message will go back to 'visible', and will be processed once again by a new lambda invocation. This will go-on until whatever is configured in your re-drive policy.

In any case, after about 4 days, messages will start to be purged off the que, the SQS que is not a permanent storage place. You cannot use SQS as permanent storage.

A short answer to your question is to fail the invocation by exiting with a non-zero status -- but beware, the message will be reprocessed, unless you have a redrive policy that will push it into the DLQ.

Comment: Might be worth noting the lambda failing doesnt make the message return to being visible, thats controlled by the default visibility period on SQS (30s). This is important because you can use your lambda to increase the invisibility period of the message it consumed, then exit with an error code, essentially scheduling the message to be consumed later